# Cannot write to postGIS by Openlayers with WriteTransction in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using **WriteTranscation()** to tell geoserver to modify the data to database, But i get this response.

```
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd"> <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode">
    <ows:ExceptionText>{www.crotec.nl}pand is read-only</ows:ExceptionText>   </ows:Exception> </ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Does somework know the reason, and how can i solve it?

Comment: make sure the table is not configured 'read-only' within the DB and alsomake sure it has a primary key. If the problem is the PK create a pk on your table and reload geoserver.

Comment: @pavlos it has pk,   could you tell where i can check if the table is configured with read only,  i use  pgadmin administration interace, i dont know where it display the "read only" setting .

Comment: This is grant setted on roles. You must know the user you used to configure your layer through geoserver. If this user or his role has grant of read-only there is your problem. Take a look here  dave.webdev.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pg/sql-grant.html may help you as long as you use pg-admin

Comment: @pavlos  actuaaly the postGIS is installed in local computer, i used the initial user role,  i checked the role on pgAdmin, i fould something by right clicking the role     ->property->SQL， in that there is a radio button with name called read only,   i dont know if it is caused by the radio button and i want to unselect it,   but the  "ok" confirm buton disable me click,  do you have ideas to change the role to enable edit

Comment: @pavlos i grant the "postgres" role with "grant all on database crotec to postgres", but still have some problem

Comment: is the PK field of your table visible in the geoserver "edit layer" area? -->Feature Type Details --> your PK name. if exist must be Nillable --> false

Comment: so you have to dig into PG to overcome it. still have the same error?